# Powemock mock inner @Autowired dependency of class

Tags: java, junit, powermock

I have `@Autowired` dependency in test that have another `@Authowired` dependency in it. I'm using

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

and

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```

in order to get spring context in my test.

I need to mock the inner dependency of `@Autowired` member. I can do this by writing following code:

```
@Autowired
private CartService cartService;

private MyValidator validator;

@Test
public void addItemToCartTest() {

 validator =  PowerMock.createMock(MyValidator.class);
 expect(validator.validate(item)).andReturn(true);
 cartService.setValidator(validator);
 PowerMock.replayAll();

 cartService.addItem(item);
     //some code
 verifyAll();
}
```

Everything works this way but I need to explicitly call set method of the cartService. I added this method just for test and now I want to remove it but if I'm not setting the validator, it not being mocked.

How can I mock it anyway?

Comment: Setup a Spring Context within your tests `@ContextConfiguration` that enables component scanning and has the validator bean that is a mock. You can call the Powermock factory method to create the mock bean.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a unit test:

Limit the scope of the test to testing a single concrete class. Consider exposing the classes dependencies through the constructor ([dependency injection](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Motivation?tm=6)) or using [Whitebox](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/BypassEncapsulation) to muck with the private internal state if you can't increase visibility of fields or setters to package private for testing.

If this test is an integration test:

Create a custom spring config (xml or pojo based) where the injected dependencies are bound to mocks. Inject the mocks as well so you can perform interaction validation. To use the custom config in your junit class see here:

http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/

You're going to want to use @ContextConfiguration on the Junit Class

Comment: I've tried to use WhiteBox but since in @Autowired service defined as interface I got exception: org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException: No instance field named "validator" could be found in the class hierarchy of CartService.

Comment: if spring is injecting the object for you, then i'd either have a separate spring configuration file for your test which binds the validator to a mock or leave the setter in but reduce visibility to package private and document that it's visible only for testing.

Comment: and if the test is meant to be a unit test, i'd forgo having spring inject everything and simply instantiate / test the implementation class directly using Whitebox or DI to seed my mock objects on the concrete impl class